# Binding ObservableCollection to selected items of a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

After hours and hours of googling, I still can't find a simple solution for binding an `ObservableCollection` to the selected items of a `ListBox` in a `TwoWay` Mode...

What I have is really simple : a `ListBox` with `SelectionMode="Multiple"`, and an `ObservableCollection<Contact>` named `SelectedContacts`. I want this two to be bound. Of course my `ListBox` has `ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"` which is another `ObservableCollection` of Contact.

Now I really can't use a `IsSelected` bool on my `Contact` items, I just can't.

Thank you !

Comment: Of course you can. That's why view models exist. Wrap your contact items into view models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There **is no simple solution**. You can't bind `SelectedItems`.

The *best* solution is to select your `Contact` items into a view model object with an `IsSelected` property, bind to that, and then run a query against the primary OC when you need to get the selected items collection.

Since you said you can't/won't do that, the next best solution would likely be to handle `SelectionChanged` in your code-behind and manually update the VM collection from there.

Comment: The principal problem with the best solution is that I'm getting all my `Contact` items from an API, so everytime my contacts are reloaded, I lost my `IsSelected` property value and my `ListBox` get emptied. I can't figure out a solution (simple or not) without breaking the MVVM pattern...

Comment: @Lucaribou Select those items into a seperate object, and reselect them back when you save. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you  @BradleyDotNET, it did the trick, I'm still thinking that the `SelectedItems` is a flaw in the ListBox architecture, but well, I just didn't think that could do it.

Comment: @Lucaribou It is a flaw, but there are several articles that explain why it is so hard to make that bindable (which is why they didn't do it).

Answer (score 1):

Since `SelectedItems` is not a `DependencyProperty` you are not allowed to use Bindings

But there is a solution, take a look at this post:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/miziel/2014/05/02/wpf-binding-listbox-selecteditems-attached-property-vs-style/

Comment: Actually, this is the good example of attached properties overusing.

Comment: I know about the `SelectedItems`, but I'm looking for a similar solution as if it was a `DependencyProperty`, I'm going to look this post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to not keep track of the selected items in your ViewModel. Instead, pass them as a CommandParameter from the UI when you are trying to do some action.

Example:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" />
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" 
        CommandParameters="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=MyListBox}" />
```